# Hadoop Vs. Disco Vs. Condor?

Tags: python, distributed-computing

I am trying to find a tool that will manage a bunch of jobs on 100 machines in a cluster (submit the jobs to the machines; make sure that jobs are run etc).

Which tool would be more simple to install / manage:

`(1) Hadoop?`

`(2) Disco?`

`(3) Condor?`

Ideally, I am searching for a solution that would be as simple as possible, yet be robust.
`Python` integration is also a plus.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm unfamiliar with Disco and Condor, but I can answer regarding Hadoop:

Hadoop pros:

- Robust and proven - probably more than anything else out there. Used by many organizations (including the one I work for) to run clusters of 100s of nodes and more.
- Large ecosystem = support + many subprojects to make life easier (e.g. Pig, Hive)
- Python support should be possible through the streaming MR feature, or maybe Jython?

Hadoop cons:

- Neither simple nor elegant (imho). You'll have to spend time learning.

Comment: A large ecosystem also means tutorials and possibly stackoverflow answers. The opportunity to ask questions (and get answers) really would be a plus for hadoop.

Comment: @extraneon Absolutely! Thanks for adding that!

Comment: Pig is not kosher :-) hence I was looking for different solutions. It appears that Hadoop is complicated to install / maintain etc (especially for a 1-person shop), hence, I a, looking for something a little more simple to maintain. Chag Pessach Sameach.

Comment: @user540009 also take a look at GridGain. I used it in the past as a more developer-friendly alternative to Hadoop. Chag Sameach.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered the Sun Grid Engine? http://wikis.sun.com/display/GridEngine/Home .